# How do I call the Win32 API function `WriteFile()` with C++ iterators?

Tags: c++, winapi, iterator

I have a class method which wraps the Win32 API function `WriteFile()`. This API function takes an `LPCVOID` argument to the data to be written. But instead, I want to pass a C++ iterator to it. How do I do it?

---

The [`WriteFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _In_         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

---

My implementation:

```
template <class Iter>
BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES BinaryFile::Write(
                        Iter Begin,
                        Iter End,
                        DWORD & dwNumberOfBytesWritten /*= DUMMY_DWORD_REFERENCE*/)
{
    if (m_nFileState != STATE_OPEN) return WRITE_FILE_NOT_OPEN;
    BOOL bResult = WriteFile((HANDLE)       m_hFile,
                            (LPCVOID)       Begin,
                            (DWORD)         sizeof(*Begin) * (End - Begin),
                            (LPDWORD)       &dwNumberOfBytesWritten,
                            (LPOVERLAPPED)  NULL);
    m_dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
    m_FilePointer += dwNumberOfBytesWritten;
    if (bResult)
        return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
    else
        return WRITE_FAILURE;
}
```

An attempt to call it:

```
TextFile::RETURN_VALUES TextFile::Write(std::vector<uint8_t> & String)
{
    DWORD dwNumberOfBytesWritten;
    BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES WriteReturn = m_File.Write(
                            String.begin(),
                            String.end(),
                            dwNumberOfBytesWritten);
    if (WriteReturn == BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES::WRITE_SUCCESSFUL)
        return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
    else if (dwNumberOfBytesWritten < String.end() - String.begin())
        return WRITE_NOT_ALL_WRITTEN;
    else
        return WRITE_FAILURE;
}
```

The compiler (VS2012) error I get:

> BinaryFile.h
>   error C2440
>   'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'LPCVOID'

Comment: If the memory is contiguous, like `std::vector`, `&*Begin` should do it. That will definitely not work for things like `std::list`, though. You can't use iterators (besides pointers, which are random-access iterators) with C functions like that, since C (particularly these functions) have no notion of them.

Comment: And if the memory is not contigious, like `std::list`, then you have to loop from `Begin` to `End` deferencing and writing each iterator one at a time.

Comment: @Remy: Bad idea.  Better to make a contiguous copy, and write it once.

Comment: It seems, that you're trying to reimplement `std::ofstream`... What is a reason to use WinAPI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of simple containers like `std:::vector<some POD type>` or `std::string`, you can do this:

```
template <class Iter>
BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES BinaryFile::Write(
                        Iter Begin,
                        Iter End,
                        DWORD & dwNumberOfBytesWritten /*= DUMMY_DWORD_REFERENCE*/)
{
    if (m_nFileState != STATE_OPEN)
        return WRITE_FILE_NOT_OPEN;

    BOOL bResult = WriteFile((HANDLE)       m_hFile,
                            (LPCVOID)       &*Begin,
                            (DWORD)         sizeof(*Begin) * (End - Begin),
                            (LPDWORD)       &dwNumberOfBytesWritten,
                            (LPOVERLAPPED)  NULL);

    m_dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
    if (!bResult)
        return WRITE_FAILURE;

    m_FilePointer += dwNumberOfBytesWritten;
    return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

But for more complex containers, like `std::list`, you have to do this instead (which will work for all containers, but only so long as they hold POD types):

```
template <class Iter>
BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES BinaryFile::Write(
                        Iter Begin,
                        Iter End,
                        DWORD & dwNumberOfBytesWritten /*= DUMMY_DWORD_REFERENCE*/)
{
    dwNumberOfBytesWritten = 0;

    if (m_nFileState != STATE_OPEN)
        return WRITE_FILE_NOT_OPEN;

    DWORD dwWritten;
    while (Begin != End)
    {
        BOOL bResult = WriteFile((HANDLE)       m_hFile,
                                (LPCVOID)       &*Begin,
                                (DWORD)         sizeof(*Begin),
                                (LPDWORD)       &dwWritten,
                                (LPOVERLAPPED)  NULL);
        m_dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
        if (!bResult)
            return WRITE_FAILURE;

        m_FilePointer += dwWritten;
        dwNumberOfBytesWritten += dwWritten;

        ++Begin;
    }

    return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

In which case `dwNumberOfBytesWritten` isn't really that meaningful.  It would make more sense to change it to `dwNumberOfItemsWritten` instead, eg:

```
template <class Iter>
BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES BinaryFile::Write(
                        Iter Begin,
                        Iter End,
                        DWORD & dwNumberOfItemsWritten /*= DUMMY_DWORD_REFERENCE*/)
{
    dwNumberOfItemsWritten = 0;

    if (m_nFileState != STATE_OPEN)
        return WRITE_FILE_NOT_OPEN;

    DWORD dwWritten;
    while (Begin != End)
    {
        BOOL bResult = WriteFile((HANDLE)       m_hFile,
                                (LPCVOID)       &*Begin,
                                (DWORD)         sizeof(*Begin),
                                (LPDWORD)       &dwWritten,
                                (LPOVERLAPPED)  NULL);
        m_dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
        if (!bResult)
            return WRITE_FAILURE;

        m_FilePointer += dwWritten;
        ++dwNumberOfItemsWritten;

        ++Begin;
    }

    return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
}

TextFile::RETURN_VALUES TextFile::Write(std::vector<uint8_t> & String)
{
    DWORD dwNumberOfItemsWritten;
    BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES WriteReturn = m_File.Write(
                            String.begin(),
                            String.end(),
                            dwNumberOfItemsWritten);
    if (WriteReturn == BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES::WRITE_SUCCESSFUL)
        return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
    else if (dwNumberOfItemsWritten < String.size())
        return WRITE_NOT_ALL_WRITTEN;
    else
        return WRITE_FAILURE;
}
```

And lastly, in either situation, don't forget that `WriteFile()` is not guaranteed to write as many bytes as you request, so you really should call it in a loop until all of the expected data has been written in full or until an error occurs, eg:

```
template <class Iter>
BinaryFile::RETURN_VALUES BinaryFile::Write(
                        Iter Begin,
                        Iter End,
                        DWORD & dwNumberOfItemsWritten /*= DUMMY_DWORD_REFERENCE*/)
{
    dwNumberOfItemsWritten = 0;

    if (m_nFileState != STATE_OPEN)
        return WRITE_FILE_NOT_OPEN;

    DWORD dwWritten;
    while (Begin != End)
    {
        LPBYTE pData = (LPBYTE) &*Begin;
        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(*Begin);

        do
        {
            BOOL bResult = WriteFile((HANDLE)       m_hFile,
                                     (LPCVOID)      pData,
                                     (DWORD)        dwSize,
                                     (LPDWORD)      &dwWritten,
                                     (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);
            m_dwLastError = ::GetLastError();
            if (!bResult)
                return WRITE_FAILURE;

            m_FilePointer += dwWritten;

            pData += dwWritten;
            dwSize -= dwWritten;
        }
        while (dwSize > 0);

        ++dwNumberOfItemsWritten;
        ++Begin;
    }

    return WRITE_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `WriteFile` inside a loop.  Instead just do `std::vector<remove_reference<decltype(*Begin)> > contig(Begin, End);` and write from `&contig[0]` onward.

Comment: Even with a contigious buffer, you still need to call `WriteFile()` in a loop for each buffer in case it writes fewer bytes than requested on any particular call. That is why it has a `DWORD` output value indicating the number of bytes actually written.

Comment: That's true, but looping to handle the extremely infrequent case of partial writes is something entirely different from intentionally making a zillion kernel transitions with a small chunk of data in each.  But you're right that I don't mean "Don't use a loop."  I mean "Don't make a separate `WriteFile` call for each datum."

Comment: Also, if `Begin` and `End` are iterators to an existing contiguous buffer, making a local contiguous buffer would be wasteful of memory. I wouldn't allocate a buffer for the entire iterator range. I do agree that `WriteFile()` is best not called for each datum, so I would instead allocate a local buffer that is an even multiple of the OS page size, say a couple of MBs at most, then loop through the iterators filling that buffer until it is full, then write it to file and clear it, repeating as needed until finished looping through the iterators.

Comment: If the dataset is extremely large, then batching is reasonable.  But a single OS page is far too small.  About 1 or 2 megabytes is optimal.  (Check the difference between sequential write and 4k random write on any disk benchmark).  `WriteFileGather` actually sounds well suited to this task, but it isn't because it requires all the pieces to be page-sized.

Answer (score 0):

You can (maybe even should) specialize your function **only** for vector's iterators and for raw pointers and deny all other. In case of vector's iterators you can pass to pointer-style function `&*Begin` as @chris said. I'm not sure, that you're able to call `operator*` for `End` iterator, but you can try this trick:

```
auto e = End;
e--;
auto pe = &*e;
e++;
```

At the end: you should check that `Begin != End` at the start of a function

Comment: Dereferencing an end iterator is typically bad, yes. The end is meant to be exclusive.

Comment: You still have to watch out for iterators that do not point to POD types. Think what would happen if a `vector<string>` were used, for instance. You could use `std::is_pod` to verify that, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right. BTW, maybe the best idea is to drop out `WriteFile` and use `std::ofstream` ? Isn't it ?